# WCF Max Instances seems to be limited to 10

Tags: wcf, iis-7.5

I have a simple WCF service hosted in IIS7.5 exposed over a wsHttp binding using message security and InstanceContextMode.PerCall

I have a simple UI that spins up a configurable number of threads, each calling the service.

I have added the perfmon counter ServiceModel4.Instances. Regardless of the number of threads created and calling the service, perfmon shows that the service creates a maximum of 10 Instances.

My client config is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>

      <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService3">
        <security mode="Message">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
            realm="" />
          <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
            algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="false" />
        </security>
      </binding>

    </wsHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>

    <endpoint address="http://localhost/NGCInstancing/Service3.svc/~/Service3.svc"
      binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService3"
      contract="NGCSecPerCall.IService3" name="WSHttpBinding_IService3">
      <identity>
        <servicePrincipalName value="host/RB-T510" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>

  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

My service config is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<system.serviceModel>
    <configuration>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="SecPerCallBehaviour">
                    <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="30" maxConcurrentSessions="1000"
                    maxConcurrentInstances="30" />
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
                <behavior name="">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BindingMessageSecPerCall" >
            <security mode="Message">
            <!-- it's by setting establishSecurityContext to false that we enable per call instancing with security -->
            <message establishSecurityContext="false" />
            </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
        <service name="ServiceInstancingDemo.Service3" behaviorConfiguration="SecPerCallBehaviour">
        <endpoint address="~/Service3.svc"
        binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BindingMessageSecPerCall"
        contract="ServiceInstancingDemo.IService3" />
        </service>
    </services>
    </configuration>
</system.serviceModel>
```

The client code is as follows:

```
private void btnSecPerCall_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i;
        int requests;
        int delay;

        lblStatus.Text = "";

        DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
        this.listBox1.Items.Add("start time=" + DateTime.Now);

        delay = Convert.ToInt16(txtDelay.Text);
        requests = Convert.ToInt16(txtRequests.Text);

        Task<string>[] result;
        result = new Task<string>[requests];

        for (i = 0; i < requests; i++)
        {
            result[i] = Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() => _ngcSecPerCall.WaitThenReturnString(delay));
        }

        for (i = 0; i < requests; i++)
        {
            this.listBox1.Items.Add(result[i].Result);
        }

        DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan ts = endTime - startTime;
        lblStatus.Text = "Finished! Time taken= " + ts.Seconds + " seconds";

        this.listBox1.Items.Add("end time=" + DateTime.Now);
    }
```

My service code is as follows:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class Service3 : IService3
{
    private int m_counter;

    public string WaitThenReturnString(int waitMilliSeconds)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(waitMilliSeconds);
        int maxT, workCT;
        System.Threading.ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out maxT, out workCT);
        m_counter++;
        return String.Format("Incrementing counter to {0}.\r\nSession Id: {1}. Threads {2}, {3}", m_counter, OperationContext.Current.SessionId, maxT, workCT);
    }
}
```

The service returns 400,400 for the number of threads.

Does anyone know why the service refused to create more that 10 instances?

If I create a copy of the service but with a a wsHttp binding that has `<security mode="None"/>` then the service happily created many more instances.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Are you testing on a Windows Server or Windows 7? The reason I ask is that IIS on the client OS versions has a 10 connection limit. This is to prevent the client OS from being used in a server environment.

Comment: This sounds promising! I am using Windows 7. I will deploy to a win2008 VM tomorrow and get back.

Comment: Yes, that was it. When i test on the Win 2008 VM it work great. Many thanks Graymatter

Answer (score 2):

The [MaxConcurrentSessions documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicethrottlingbehavior.maxconcurrentsessions.aspx) mentions an optimization for client requests that come from the same AppDomain. Your sample code is basically hitting the same socket on the service. Since there is some throttling done per client, that may be affecting your service behavior. Also, 10 happens to be the default value for MaxConcurrentSessions so it may be that your config is not changing the WCF default value.

Enabling security affects the total threads because it establishes a "session" per client so that each request sent does not need to be authenticated on every call. Those security "sessions" count toward the MaxConcurrentSessions total.

Comment: It may be worth me adding that I have an implemented the same service with a different binding. The new binding is also wsHttp but has <security mode="None"/>. When I run the same client against this service then the service happily spins up more than 10 instances. I guess that for the new binding the sessions are not being used because there's no need to establish a security context. I think you're onto something with the fact that 10 is the default MaxConcurrentSessions but of course my config attempts to change this value to 1000. Anyone know way of checking actual settings used at runtime?

Comment: I moved my tests onto a Win2008 VM and it now works great - I get 61 instances rather than the 10 I was getting on my Win7 host. Thanks very much Sixto Saez!

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the client and server on the same machine? Then they might be fighting for available threads.

If you are running on a different PC, please ensure you have done the following config changes on both client and server.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/quickwins.aspx

It is possible that the client is not generating more than 10 requests to the same server. So, please try the above configs first on both client and server.

And of course, you must have a Windows Server. Otherwise it will be the IIS limit on Windows 7.