# WCF Service only handling 10 concurrent calls regardless of what I do

Tags: wcf, concurrency

I realize there's a ton of questions relating to this already but regardless of what I try, there seems to be something different about my problem that keeps any of the other solutions from fixing it.

Here's the problem: I have a simple WCF service.  It seems to only allow 10 concurrent calls, I need to to support more than that.  This is regardless of what I set my `maxConcurrentCalls` to in my config.  In this case, to simplify the problem I don't even have a real .Net WCF client calling it, I'm simply using fiddler on a few machines to issue a bunch of HTTP posts to the service.  They all work individually, but I see them come in 10 at a time.  As #1 finishes, #11 starts and so on.

My service is a simple "sleep for 30 seconds and return a string" for this example.

Below is my web.config.  You can see I have cranked up my `maxConcurrentCalls` and my `maxConcurrentSessions` to more than the defaults.  This seems to have no impact at all as I still only see 10 concurrent requests at a time.

What part am I missing to crank this up to allow more concurrent requests?

**Edit: This is hosted in IIS 7.5.**

Web.config:

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <security>
        <authentication>
            <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
        </authentication>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                <serviceThrottling 
                    maxConcurrentCalls="32" 
                    maxConcurrentInstances="2147483647" 
                    maxConcurrentSessions="20"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Service:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace WCFTestService
{
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Threading;

    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
    public class TestService : ITestService
    {

        public string RequestIdentifier { get; set; }

        public int i;

        public string DoWork(string id)
        {
            var secondsBeforeResponding = 20;

            i++;

            this.RequestIdentifier = id;

            Debug.WriteLine("Request: " + id + " Instance:" + i.ToString() + " Thread:" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString() + " Time:" + DateTime.Now.ToString());

            Thread.Sleep(secondsBeforeResponding * 1000);

            Debug.WriteLine("                                                          Done with request: " + this.RequestIdentifier);

            return "Done with request: " + this.RequestIdentifier;
        }
    }
}
```

ITestService:

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.NotAllowed)]
public interface ITestService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string DoWork(string requestIdentifier);
}
```

Output:

```
Request: b3 Instance:1 Thread:54 Time:4/13/2013 1:50:31 PM <!--- this is the first 10, they all start at pretty much the same time
Request: b4 Instance:1 Thread:47 Time:4/13/2013 1:50:31 PM
Request: b1 Instance:1 Thread:48 Time:4/13/2013 1:50:31 PM
Request: b2 Instance:1 Thread:45 Time:4/13/2013 1:50:31 PM
Request: b5 Instance:1 Thread:44 Time:4/13/2013 1:50:31 PM
Request: b6 Instance:1 Thread:42 Time:4/13/2013 1:50:31 PM
Request: b7 Instance:1 Thread:41 Time:4/13/2013 1:50:32 PM
Request: b8 Instance:1 Thread:39 Time:4/13/2013 1:50:32 PM
Request: b9 Instance:1 Thread:40 Time:4/13/2013 1:50:33 PM
Request: b10 Instance:1 Thread:38 Time:4/13/2013 1:50:34 PM
                                                          Done with request: b3
                                                          Done with request: b4
                                                          Done with request: b1
                                                          Done with request: b2
Request: b11 Instance:1 Thread:35 Time:4/13/2013 1:50:51 PM  <--- this request only starts after the first one finishes
Request: b13 Instance:1 Thread:45 Time:4/13/2013 1:50:51 PM
Request: b14 Instance:1 Thread:54 Time:4/13/2013 1:50:51 PM
Request: b12 Instance:1 Thread:37 Time:4/13/2013 1:50:51 PM
                                                          Done with request: b5
Request: b15 Instance:1 Thread:44 Time:4/13/2013 1:50:51 PM
                                                          Done with request: b6
Request: b16 Instance:1 Thread:42 Time:4/13/2013 1:50:51 PM
                                                          Done with request: b7
Request: b17 Instance:1 Thread:41 Time:4/13/2013 1:50:52 PM
                                                          Done with request: b8
Request: b18 Instance:1 Thread:39 Time:4/13/2013 1:50:52 PM
                                                          Done with request: b9
Request: b19 Instance:1 Thread:40 Time:4/13/2013 1:50:53 PM
                                                          Done with request: b10
Request: b20 Instance:1 Thread:38 Time:4/13/2013 1:50:54 PM
...
...
...
```

Comment: Is this service being hosted in IIS (which version?) or are you doing self-hosting?

Comment: Hosted in IIS.  IIS version 7.5.

Comment: What binding are you using?  Also, the default for `maxConcurrentCalls` is 16, not 10.  The default for `maxConcurrentSesions` is 10.  I would suggest writing a simple console app to create a client (that creates a channel) to test the max conccurency - I would not be surprised to see it work in that case.

Comment: @Tim - basicHTTP binding in this case.  In the orig post you can see that I've simplified the problem by eliminating any client at all, I'm simply issuing HTTP posts to it via multiple Fiddlers.  This way I don't have to muck with any client settings at all.  The behavior I'm seeing (only handling 10 concurrent requests at a time) is all based on what the service on the server is allowing, not anything to do with the clients.

Comment: @BobBland - Could it be an issue with thread limits in the pool (either for IIS or the CLR)?  A max thread limit of 10 by default seems awfully low, but maybe it's worth looking into?

Comment: Did you try to look on SvcTraceViewer.exe? Also, I'd try to host in in some other way, for example console app - just to be sure iis pool / site definitions are not the source of the issue.

Comment: I believe this is an OS thing, check the duplicate link I provided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could be running into OS limitations.  Try to deploy your service out to a server and reproduce the behavior from there.

Comment: This is exactly what it was.  I deployed my test application off of my windows 7 development box to a 2008 server and everything worked as it should.. meaning the `maxConcurrentCalls` in the config correctly controlled how many incoming connections I could handle.  [Link to a better explanation here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822477/wcf-max-instances-seems-to-be-limited-to-10)